# Pattern in alternating sum of cube be a square number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to show

Let

$$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n^2-2n+1}(-1)^kk^3$$

1. $\mid S(n)\mid $ is always be perfect square number for $n=1,2,3,...$.
2. $\mid\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^kk^3\mid$ is perfect square number if and only if $m=2n^2-2n+1$ for $n=1,2,3,...$

Example $|S(2)|= 81=3^2$

I came across this problem through observation. Thanks for your time and help and apologies for the short question.

Comment: Recast the sum as $\sum(2k+1)^3-\sum(2k)^3$ with appropriate limits and work through the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof of the first part,
that the sum to
$2n^2-2n+1$
is a square.

Note:
I added a proof that
the sum to an even number of terms
can not be a square.

Let
$c(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k k^3
$.

$\begin{array}\\
c(2n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k k^3\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} ((-1)^{2k-1} (2k-1)^3+(-1)^{2k} (2k)^3)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-(2k-1)^3+(2k)^3)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-(8k^3-12k^2+6k-1)+8k^3)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (12k^2-6k+1)\\
&=12\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-6\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+n\\
&=2n(n+1)(2n+1)-3n(n+1)+n\\
&=4 n^3 + 3 n^2\\
\text{so}\\
c(2n+1)
&=c(2n)-(2n+1)^3\\
&=4 n^3 + 3 n^2-(8n^3+12n^2+6n+1)\\
&=-(4n^3+9n^2+6n+1)\\
\text{so}\\
c(2n^2-2n+1)
&=-(4(n^2-n)^3+9(n^2-n)^2+6(n^2-n)+1)\\
&=-(2 n^3 - 3 n^2 + 3 n - 1)^2
\qquad\text{(according to Wolfy)}\\
\end{array}
$

---

If
$c(2n) = m^2$ then
$m^2
=4 n^3 + 3 n^2
$.
If $n=2^ab$
where $b$ is odd then
$m^2
=2^{3a+2}b^3+3\cdot2^{2a}b^2
=2^{2a}b^2(2^{a+2}b+3)
$
so
$m = 2^abc$ where
$c^2=2^{a+2}b+3
$
which can not be since
all odd squares are
equal to 1 mod 4.

Comment: Does this show that the only squares are $c\!\left(2n^2-2n+1\right)$?

Comment: No. There could be other odd solutions. They would be from $m^2=4n^3+9n^2+6n+1$.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was missing something. Note that $4n^3+9n^2+6n+1=(4n+1)(n+1)^2$. From there...

Answer (score 2):

Define the alternating sum of cubes sequence ([OEIS A232599](https://oeis.org/A232599))
$$ a_n := \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k k^3. \tag{1} $$
An alternate formula
$$ a_n = \frac{1 + (-1)^n (4 n^3 + 6 n^2 - 1)}8 \tag{2} $$
can be proved by verifying that $\,a_n-a_{n-1} = (-1)^n n^3.\,$
Note that $\,a_{2n} = n^2(4n+3)\,$ is never a square since $\,4n+3\,$
is never square. However, $\,a_{2n+1} = -(n+1)^2(4n+1)\,$ and
$\,4n+1 = (2k+1)^2\,$ only when $\, n = k^2+k\,$ and
then $$ 2n+1 = 2(k^2+k)+1 = k^2+(k+1)^2 \tag{3} $$ is
[OEIS sequence A001844](https://oeis.org/A001844) "Centered
square numbers". Verify that
$$ a_{n^2+(n+1)^2} = -b_n^2,\quad b_n := n^3+(n+1)^3 \tag{4} $$
where $\,b_n\,$ is [OEIS sequence A005895](https://oeis.org/A005895)
"Centered cube numbers".

Answer (score 2):

Writing $(2n)^3-(2n-1)^3$ as a binomial polynomial
$$
(2n)^3-(2n-1)^3=24\binom{n}{2}+6\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{0}\tag1
$$
allows us to sum, using the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity),
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^n\left((2j)^3-(2j-1)^3\right)
&=24\binom{n+1}{3}+6\binom{n+1}{2}+\binom{n+1}{1}\tag{2a}\\
&=4\left(n^3-n\right)+3\left(n^2+n\right)+(n+1)\tag{2b}\\[6pt]
&=4n^3+3n^2+1\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting the $j=0$ term yields
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\left((2j)^3-(2j-1)^3\right)=(4n+3)n^2\tag3
$$
Subtracting $(3)$ from $(2n+1)^3$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
(2n+1)^3-\sum_{j=1}^n\left((2j)^3-(2j-1)^3\right)
&=4n^3+9n^2+6n+1\tag{4a}\\
&=(4n+1)(n+1)^2\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
The quadratic residues mod $4$ are $0$ and $1$. Thus, $(3)$ can never yield a perfect square, but $(4)$ can, but if and only if $4n+1=(2k-1)^2=4k^2-4k+1$. That is, $n=k^2-k$ for some integer $k$. That is, the highest cube included is $(2k^2-2k+1)^3$.

**Conclusion:**

Since $(3)$ cannot be a perfect square, and $(4)$ is a perfect square if and only if $n=k^2-k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we get that the alternating sum of cubes is a perfect square if and only if the highest cube included in the sum is $(2n+1)^3=\left(2k^2-2k+1\right)^3$.

Comment: I missed your $100 \pi$ reputation ! Congratulations for the  $\sqrt{10^5}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JoDu.png) is a flashback to July 3, when I was closest to $100\pi k$. I had an avatar customized for Independence Day.

Comment: This is a nice avatar ! How do you make that ?

Comment: I put the specs for a flag into Mathematica and made a flag to insert between the background and the eyes. It makes the flag look like a mask.

Comment: This answer is complete; it shows exactly when the sum in the question can be a perfect square. At least one other answer does not prove that it gets all the perfect squares. What is wrong with this answer to deserve a downvote? (Note that I am not advocating that any other answer deserves a downvote, as the others are useful, too.)